# Getting variable from a function

Tags: function, lua

```
function isEven(x)
    print("Checking if "..x.." is even.\nWill return state as 1 if true.")

    if math.fmod(x, 2) == 0 then
        state = 1
    end

    return state
end
```

I know that I can just run isEven and then use the state variable. But is there a way to do it in one line?

Like `isEven(8).state`?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: You could just use the return value? What are you doing with the `state` variable here?

Comment: You can simply write `isEven(8)` without appending `state`: `if isEven(8) == 1 then ...`.

Comment: This is a potential bug waiting to happen. `state` here is a **global variable**, which is why the OP was confused. Almost always programmers want `local` variables in functions. You should define variables like this as as `local` and not use them as a global variables.

Answer (score 1):

As Egor said in a comment, this is precisely what return values are meant to do. When you see a function call in your code, such as `isEven(8)`, it evaluates into that function's return value.

```
function isEven(x)
    print("Checking if "..x.." is even")
    return (math.fmod(x, 2) == 0)
end

print( isEven(8) )
print( isEven(7) )

if isEven(8) then
    print("a")
else
    print("b")
end
```

Finally, I would just like to point out a couple of things about the isEven function: First of all if you want you could use the `%` operator instead of math.fmod. Secondly, in the example I used the function returns a boolean value (true or false) instead of a number (0 or 1).